# Return value for MeasureOverride, if constraint.Width is Infinity and all available space should be used?

Tags: wpf-controls

I am writing a custom control which inherits from FrameworkElement. I use DrawingVisual to render to the screen. Therefore, I have to calculate myself the optimal size of the Visuals I draw. If HorizontalAlignment is set to Stretch, I would like to use all available space. Only WPF doesn't tell how much space is really available :-(

In MeasureOverride, the constraint.Width is Infinity. I need to return a desired size which is less than Infinity, otherwise I get the exception "InvalidOperationException: Layout measurement override of element 'xyz' should not return PositiveInfinity as its DesiredSize, even if Infinity is passed in as available size."

I tried to return 0 in the hope that Arrange would pass all the available space this time, since in MeasureOverride it said Infinity width is available. But ArrangeOverride says the arrangeBounds.Width is 0.

I tried to return an arbitrary width (well, actually I returned the Monitor width to MeasureOverride), but then ArrangeOverride tells me I can use the complete monitor, which is, of course, not true :-(

So which width do I return in MeasureOverride to get the maximum space really available ?

**Update 23.1.23**

My control is in a library and has no idea who is the container holding it. I inherit from that control to make many different controls, for example a line graph that can contain millions of measurements. So if there is unlimited space, the graph gets millions of pixel wide. If the space is limited, let's say 1000 pixels, then the graph displays in 1 pixel the average of thousands of measurements.

[image]

Comment: It sounds like your control is inside of some other container that actually has an infinite width available. A ScrollViewer can have an infinite size because it grows to hold all of the content passed to it. Grids and other controls can also have infinite sizes to hold all of their content. usually, problems like this come from the containers of the controls having infinite width.

Comment: So unless MeasureOverride is passed something not infinite, the framework thinks that you really do have infinite width available. Look at your XAML and the things that contain your control and see how they are defined. Maybe swap your control for something stretchy like a StackPanel and add content to it to see if it makes it's container grow beyond what is expected.

Maybe post some XAML of your page, or whatever you are using to hold your control.

Answer (score 0):

After using WPF now for nearly 20 years, I think the proper solution is to raise an exception when the available width is Infinity, but my control cannot deal with that. The exception demands that the control is put into a container which gives limited width to its children.

For example a ScrollViewer gives unlimited space to its children. But since my line graph, or any other control I design that can not deal with unlimited space, gets unreasonably big, it is better to alert the developer using the control immediately that the control needs to be hosted in a container like a Grid, where the Grid tells the child the exact size available. Of course, also the Grid might give unlimited space when the column width is set to auto, but in this case my Control should raise an exception, so that the column width can get changed to a number of pixels or *.